# Resizing ScrollView in playmode in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

Im searching for a way to resize my scrollview in playmode like you can do with your file explorer.

I was trying to find any solution at the internet but there was only ways to make scallable ui

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.